# Using SQL on an Excel Worksheet has strange results

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have macro where users select multiple files.  Each file is copied to a new worksheet in the macro.  After all of the files are selected, the macro uses SQL to extract the data from each worksheet and pastes it on a "data" sheet.  Once the data has been moved to the "data" worksheet a pivot table is created.

The user notified us that one of the columns in the Pivot table is over by $ 1.00.  What I found is the one amount (13.24) from a worksheet appears as different amount (14.24) on the "data" sheet.

This is the code that extracts the data from each worksheet:

```
vsql = "SELECT [Region Name], [Site Ledger Code],[GL Account], [DeptID], [Emp Number], [Emp Name]," _
                        & "IIF (ISNUMERIC(MID([Description],1,3)) = TRUE, MID([Description],1,3), """"), " _
                        & "IIF (ISNUMERIC(MID([Description],1,3)) = TRUE, MID([Description],7,(LEN ([Description])-6)), [Description]), " _
                        & "IIF ([TTYPE] = ""Debit"",  [Amount], 0) AS Debit, " _
                        & "IIF ([TTYPE] = ""Credit"", [Amount], 0) as Credit, " _
                        & "[Amount], [Pay Date]" _
                        & "FROM [" & WrkShtName & "$]" _
                        & "WHERE [Description] <> ""Net Pay"" and [Description] <> ""NPA - Net Pay Adjustment (US)"""
```

When I look at the recordset, the amounts do not appear as amounts but rather as dates.  Then when they get pasted on the "data" sheet, they appear as amounts.  All of the amounts are fine except the 13.24.  Another line in the data is -13.24 and it appears on the "data" sheet as -13.24.

I don't understand why the positive 13.24 comes over as 14.24.  Is 13.24 a special number in SQL or Excel?

Thanks for any help or suggestions you have before I lose the rest of my hair / mind......

Comment: impossible to tell without seeing the data all the data but I would guess that you have a $1 amount somewhere that has the same properties/dimensions/attributes or whatever you want to term them, as the 13.24 amount. I would filter the data sheet down by filtering the dimensions down to match the 13.24 record and see what you get. BTW: I would suggest power query could do all your VBA does quite easily, just a thought..

Comment: @AlanSchofield....Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm unable to show the data as it is payroll information.  The macro goes sheet by sheet and is only extracting the data on a particular sheet.  The change occurs at that point but I'll check the previous sheets and see if this employee exists on there as well.  Appreciate the help..

Comment: Your query doesn't appear to be **sum**ming at all, so it must be a conversion error. I'd investigate the fact that the recordset is appearing as dates as it may be related.